# Request resource does not allow request data with POST requests and 413 request entity too large

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

Whenever I click on a button to retrieve from database, I encounter the following error message below. This happens randomly. Sometimes when I click on the same button, it is able to retrieve successfully (no error is shown).

I am currently using java with Websphere server. Would like to ask what could be the possible cause?

Thank you

```
Found

The requested resource /webapp/XXX/XXXXX does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

Additionally, a 413 Request Entity Too Large error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a copy of IBM HTTP Server between your browser and WebSphere and it doesn't have the fix for PI54415. Randomly,  Contnet-Length: 0 requests trigger a 413 due to an uninitialized variable.

Comment: is there anyway the codes can be done in the application side to resolve this issue? thanks!

Comment: No, the request doesn't reach your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the 413 if your request or response has a large number of headers. If passing thru WAS web server plugin, the default is 300 headers (search on the custom property MaxHTTPHeaders to change) and WebSphere has a default of maximum of 50 by default (see http channel Maximum headers field).